# One table has two same joins in another table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have one table called `image` and another table called `duplicate`. There are two `OneToMany` relations are associated.

[image]

I am not quite sure whether below implementation is the right approach for that. Moreover whether we require that second `private List<DuplicateEntity> duplicateEntities2;` ?

**ImageEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class ImageEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "filename")
    private String fileName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "imageEntity1")
    private List<DuplicateEntity> duplicateEntities1;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "imageEntity2")
    private List<DuplicateEntity> duplicateEntities2;
}
```

**DuplicateEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "duplicate")
public class DuplicateEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_a_id")
    private ImageEntity imageEntity1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_b_id")
    private ImageEntity imageEntity2;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the mapping looks correct. As for why this is needed I guess you should address this question to somebody how more aware about business logic of your app.

Comment: do we still need that second `private List<DuplicateEntity> duplicateEntities2;` ?

Comment: Yes, these two `List<DuplicateEntity>` can have completely different items.